# Top 10 largest values in one column and smallest in another column, Dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do a new dataframe with Top 10 teams with largest goal average and smalest matches played, i need to filter all the dataframe

```
new_df = mundialestotales_df.nlargest(10, ['Prom. de Gol'])
```

Here i get the largest but i can't join with the smalest matches played

Y try to do a 2 news dataframes and join them, but that don't work

Comment: please provide a minimal example (maybe with 3 largest/smallest)

Answer (score 0):

See dummy data below, you can tweak to your dataset since none was provided. We can create our large / small dataframes and then concat them back together.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'State':['MO','IA','KS','NE','AL','KY','OH','IL'],
    'Pop':[1000,5000,8950,10000,12500,800,15000,30000],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

display(df)

large_df = df[df['Pop'].rank(ascending=False) <= 3]
display(large_df)

small_df = df[df['Pop'].rank(ascending=True) <= 3]
display(small_df)


combined_df = pd.concat([large_df,small_df]).reset_index()
display(combined_df)
```